# Tightest way to call code in C#

Tags: c#

This may not have an answer or be up for debate.  I wanted the most succinct way to call functionality.

I came up with this

```
public class Initialize
{
    public static bool Me
    {
        get
        {
            {
                // My custom functionality
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I called it

```
Initialize.Me
```

It's a compile error because it says only increment decrement assignment etc allowed.

I know I can add () and be done with it.  But I was just trying to think of a clever way to have functionality that is like a period delimited sentence without parentheses after each word.

Comment: that code style is called `Visual Basic`  (and I think you'd have to add the semi colon too for C#)

Comment: The most succinct way to call functionality is to call a method on a class: `SomeClass.Initialize()`. Look at fluent APIs, usually they implement chaining and lambdas in order to create a 'readable' collection of operations. Also in your example, you can't add `()` since you have created a static getter, not a method

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 2):

A fluent API is usually the most natural way to do something like this. Especially if you allow chaining:

e.g.

```
// Each method returns the object so you can chain
public class ConfigurationSettings
{
    public ConfigurationSettings Initialize()
    {
        // Init code here
        return this;
    }

    public ConfigurationSettings WithConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        // Do stuff with connection string
        return this;
    }

    public ConfigurationSettings InSingleUserMode()
    {
        // Set single user mode etc...

        return this;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
 var config = new ConfigurationSettings();

 config.Initialize()
       .WithConnectionString("someServer...")
       .InSingleUserMode();
```

If I'm way off the mark here, please clarify your question